# System.out.print() is not working?

Tags: eclipse

```
package main;

public class Counter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 100000;

    while (x < 0) {
        x -= 7;
        System.out.print(x);
    }

    for (int y = 10; y < 0; y = y - 7) {
        System.out.print("lol");
    }
}
}
```

This code is not printing on my eclipse console, but I can't find any errors or problems with my code - I expect it to print a pattern of numbers. Help is appreciated.

Answered:

```
package main;

public class Counter {

public static void main(String[] facepalm) {
    int x = 100000;

    while (x > 0) {
        x -= 7;
        System.out.print(x);
    }

    for (int y = 10; y < 0; y = y - 7) {
        System.out.print("lol");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Invert your `<` to `>` and try again.

Comment: Looks like you got some < and > the wrong way round..

Comment: Yup I am terribly annoyed with myself - I've been doing this type of code for ages! I'm glad it wasn't a problem with my programming, just my terrible logic.

Comment: package main;

public class Counter {

 public static void main(String[] facepalm) {
  int x = 100000;
  
  while (x > 0) {
   x -= 7;
   System.out.print(x);
  }
  
  for (int y = 10; y > 0; y = y - 7) {
   System.out.print("lol");
  }
 }
}

Comment: You might want to revisit the answer you edited into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is failing.

```
while (x < 0) {
```

will immediately fail, since x = 10000, which is greater than 0.

Same with the for loop.

Comment: I feel so stupid now, must have wrote that too quickly. Thank you XD

Answer (score 0):

Change the '`<0`'s in the while and for conditions to `>0`. Note that the body of `while` and `for` keeps running until the condition evaluates to False.

```
public class Counter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
int x = 100000;

while (x > 0) {
    x -= 7;
    System.out.print(x);
}

for (int y = 10; y > 0; y = y - 7) {
    System.out.print("lol");
}
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you as well! Sorry, I was able to understand the first one that bit better, but this answer had the exact same idea.